# how to display and raise warnings in release pipeline for Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

In my azure devops release pipeline, i'm running a python script, which eventually logs warning or error based on the my custom logger package.
So, in my std output of the azuredevops I see it's working fine.

But, I'm wondering is it possible to display the number of warnings or error on the badge like this below image. 
I think, you have  to use [command line loggings](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md). But question comes how can I track the warnings or errors from AzDevops standard output using python.

Any idea and suggestions are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried using this in my python package and it works the way I wanted to.

```
subprocess.call(["echo", "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]some warning"])
```

May be someone can get help out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize output the [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) from python with a print function call (python3 - if using python 2, you can import print function from futures)

```
print("##[group]Beginning of a group")
print("##[warning]Warning message")
print("##[error]Error message")
print("##[section]Start of a section")
print("##[debug]Debug text")
print("##[command]Command-line being run")
print("##[endgroup]")
```